# Getting back original signal using JTransform method realInverse

Tags: java, signal-processing, fft

I was playing with JTransforms realForwardFull and RealInverse to test how they work.
My understanding is that after you pass say an audio signal to realForwardFull and then apply RealInverse, you should get back the same signal. 
So here is what I am doing.

```
double[] a1 = getAudioSignal();

DoubleDDT_1D fft = new DoubleFFT_1D(a1.length);
double[] fftData = new double[a1.length * 2];
for(int i=0; i<fftData.length; i++) {
        fftData[i] = a1[i]; // real part
        fftData[fftData.length+i] = 0; // imaginary parts
}
fft.realForwardFull(fftData);

//Do an inverse to get back the signal
fft.realInverse(fftData, false);
```

My question is should the fftData after the inverse fft (realInverse) contain the same data as in a1, the original audio signal?
I tested this and checked if all the even indexes (real part) fftData[2k] was the same as indexes in a1, its not so.

```
for(int k=0; k<a1.length; k++) {
 if(a[k] == fftData[2k]) {
    printSame();
  } else {
    printDiff();
}
```

I see that the output in the array after realInverse is very different.
How do I get the original signal back?

Comment: You seem to have a few errors in your code which will prevent it from compiling. Did you mean `DoubleFFT_1D fft` instead of `DoubleDDT_1D fft`? also the loop should use `a1.length` instead.

Answer (score 2):

As per the javadoc of [`realForwardFull`](http://incanter.org/docs/parallelcolt/api/edu/emory/mathcs/jtransforms/fft/DoubleFFT_1D.html#realForwardFull%28double[]%29) you need to call `complexInverse` to recover the original signal. Since you want the original points you should enable scaling which will divide the values by `N`:

```
fft.realForwardFull(fftData);

//Do an inverse to get back the signal
fft.complexInverse(fftData, true);
```

Also your checking logic is broken. You cannot check double equality like that because of rounding errors. You should check it like this using an epsilon error tolerance:

```
for(int k=0; k<a1.length; k++) {
   if(Math.abs(a1[k] - fftData[2*k]) < 1e-6) {
      printSame();
   } else {
      printDiff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun transformAndInvert() {
    var input = audioData.toFloatArray()

    val fft = FloatFFT_1D(minBuffer.toLong())
    val fftData = FloatArray(minBuffer * 2) { 0.0f }
    for (i in input.indices) {
        fftData[2*i] = input[i] // real part & img will be 0
    }
    fft.realForward(fftData)

    fft.realInverse(fftData, true)

    val output = FloatArray(minBuffer) { 0.0f }

    for (i in output.indices) {
        output[i] = fftData[2*i]
    }

    return output
}
```